# No values passing when calling MVC Controller's method from html file by AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to call MVC Controller's method from outside html.(Currently testing in local)
I'm calling method from Ajax in js file. request is hitting to the controller's method but no model values are passing to the method([Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXUXp.jpg)). Where i'm doing wrong ?

**In Out side js file calling from a html page**

```
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $("input#name").val();
                var email = $("input#email").val();
                var message = $("textarea#message").val();
                debugger;
                var details= {Name :"Scott", EmailAddress:"abc@sample.com", Message:"Message" };
                $.ajax({                
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:61007/Home/InsertInquery",
                    // data: JSON.stringify({
                        // Name: name,
                        // EmailAddress: email,
                        // Message: message
                    // }),
                    data: JSON.stringify(details),
                    contentType: "application/json;",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function() {
                        // Success message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                        //clear all fields
                        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        // Fail message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                        //clear all fields
                        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                    },
                })
            },
```

**In Mvc controller**

```
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
            public JsonResult InsertInquery([FromBody]Email details)
            {
                try
                {
                    return Json("Sucess");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json("Fail");
                }
            }
```

**Model in MVC project**

```
public class Email
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you try to replace `data: JSON.stringify(details)` with `data: details`? You should pass object to server, and not string.

Comment: @SergeyFadeev : Thank you very much Sir It works